# Large nested dropdown list in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've got a dropdown menu that has a lot of nested information in it. Meaning something like this:

```
Parent 1
  Child 1
  Child 2
  Child 3
    Grandchild 1
    Grandchild 2
    Grandchild 3
    ...
    Grandchild 15
  ...
  Child 25
Parent 2
Parent 3
```

I need to find a way to elegantly let a user go through the nested dropdowns. This is the closest thing that I could find online to what I need: http://dojo.telerik.com/oxEVa however, when you start to add a bunch of children to where it scrolls, and then you add a grandchild, the scrolling on the children breaks completely. Does anyone know of a menu/dropdown/combobox directive or library that I can use to accomplish showing this much data to a user and allowing them to select it easily?

Comment: Do most clients know what they're looking for when using the dropdown? If so, I'd suggest using Autocomplete like this example: https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.5/demo/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AngularJS UI Tree](https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example). It can be a little confusing at the beginning, but it works fine with nested structures. You would have to create a template which be used to render a node and its children:

```
<!-- Nested node template -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
  <div ui-tree-handle>
    {{node.title}}
  </div>
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.nodes">
    <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" ui-tree-node  ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
    </li>
  </ol>
</script>
```

And then use it on the define the tree:

```
<div ui-tree>
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="data" id="tree-root">
    <li ng-repeat="node in data" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```